# What types of error ought to utilise Ruby's Exception class, and what handling strategies for others?

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling

The context is a CLI chess game project that I'm building, and handling conditions such as user input format errors, and validating chess moves against various game and piece rules. I'm seeking guidance on the most appropriate techniques to handle these sorts of cases/conditions/errors – using Exception classes, writing my own rescue methods, and or any other approaches.

For example, in the below method I've written a custom 'case/condition handler' type method which simply `puts` a message about the problem to the user, then attempts the code again, effectively looping until the user inputs the correct format, like this:

Game#get_move & #rescue_invalid_format_error:

```
def get_move
  ...
  return rescue_invalid_format_error(move) unless chess_format?(move)
  ...
end

def rescue_invalid_format_error(move)
   puts "your move; '#{move}' was not formatted correctly, it should be formatted like; 'a1,a2', try again..."
   get_move
end
```

Then in other code I've ended up building custom Exception classes, like this:

input_errors.rb:

```
class InputError < StandardError
  def initialize(message = 'Input error')
    super(message)
  end
end
```

and upon an 'error' situation raising Exception objects, like:

```
def add_move(indexed_move)
    if index_format?(indexed_move)
      true_move?(indexed_move) ? @moves << indexed_move : (raise InputError.new("Input; #{indexed_move} does not represent an actual move"))
    else
      raise InputError.new("Indexed_move; #{indexed_move} should be formatted like 'iiii'")
    end
  end
```

*(though I've not wrapped any code that calls the above `#add_move` with `begin rescue`  blocks because I think that somehow an `InputError` is handling the exceptions already, somewhere in its ancestry code (though I'm not certain)).*

So, the essence of my question is; what's the right way, in Ruby to handle what type of conditions with what type of error handling methods/strategies?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "right way" to use exceptions in your software design. For example, even the popular [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide) basically ignores the question. The strongest recommendation it makes is to [not use exceptions for control flow](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#using-exceptions-for-flow-of-control), which is pretty widely accepted among all modern programming languages.

That being said, here are the guidelines I use (in Ruby as well as other languages).

## Use exceptions for complex errors in libraries

If you are developing a gem that you expect to be reused across several applications, exceptions can be a good way to return information-rich errors from your library. For example, this style is used in several standard parts of Ruby such as the `File` class.

Be careful though: your library should assume that these exceptions might be caught and so it should leave itself in some kind of reasonable state when that happens. You wouldn't want to throw a pretty custom exception only for that to be caught and now your library is in some unexpected state where the caller ends up with a non-pretty `RuntimeError` any time they try to do anything.

An exception to this use of exceptions: if your library's error states are very simple, there isn't much benefit to throwing a custom exception. The main benefit there is the information communicated in the custom type and message. So if you don't need that, consider simply returning `nil` to indicate an error.

## Use exceptions for *truly exceptional* situations in apps

If you're building a user-facing app (which includes CLI), reserve exceptions for those situations in code where something really should never happen, but technically it could e.g., you have an array index that should always be valid but somehow the array is too small, a variable should have already been initialized but somehow it's still `nil`, stuff like that.

Another way to put it: only use exceptions in those cases where you *wouldn't want to catch it*, and the exception is more of a way to show you which of your assumptions were wrong so you can fix the bug. One nice thing about this usage is that you usually get it for free in Ruby without any custom code, for example you get `NoMethodError` and it tells you exactly what went wrong. Usually the only place you'd want to catch such exceptions is some high-level `begin rescue` around the entire application for prettying it up with a "Sorry, something went wrong" message.

In particular, getting input from the user and that input being invalid is entirely unexceptional. Users do that all the time. Usually in my CLI apps I'll add a helper function that takes the prompt for the user, an explanation of what the input should look like, and it internally loops forever until they input something correct. Such a method does not need any way to represent errors since it either returns valid input or it never returns at all.

## In general, prefer existing exception types

Before you declare a custom exception class, double check that none of the [existing exception types](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Exception.html) work for your situation.

Comment: An exceptionally helpful answer there @max, genuinely, despite the pun. Thanks very much for taking the time to write that up and for providing me with that guidance. I think that my error and exception related thinking was floored in that I was defining an exception far too broadly and was therefore considering the exceptions device for use in control flow.

Comment: I'll read your answer a few times and do some further research and reading on the subject to really try to distill this.

Answers to these things still somewhat evade me though;
- difference, if any, between an error and an exception?
- are exceptions there to assist the developer or the user?
- why bother custom raising exceptions at all, as Ruby, I think, catches all of them anyway with a helpful error type and a message?

Comment: In Ruby there is not much difference between errors and exceptions. Just a name difference. Custom exceptions are most useful for library development, so that users of your library can catch your special exceptions and not exceptions from other libraries or normal Ruby code.